# Is there any generic Maven code generator?

Tags: java, maven, code-generation

I am currently working on a project, that makes intense usage of code generation for various purposes. One generator generates SQL scripts from jpa entities. Another generates DTOs from pojos, another generates the JPA2.0 meta model, jet another generates some xml and schema files based on Java classes ... each generator works completely different needs to be configured differently.

My question now is ... is there any generic maven code generator plugin out there with the following attributes:
- Creates a pojo model of a Java class (Names, Properties, Annotation, Methods ...)
- Uses templates for defining the output that uses the pojo model to generate any output.
- Allows me to specify multiple templates for one class
- Allows me to generate code and resources
- Allows me to generate a base class to target/generated-sources and a dummy implementation to src/main/java which simply extends the base class (If the dummy class in src/main/java exists, nothing happens, if it doesn't it generates such a dummy class. This code is checked in to the SCM and allows extending the generated classes manually)

I am using the Flexmojos GraniteDS plugin for generating my ActionScript model code, but it's pretty specialized for that particular purpose.

I think such a generic generator would make things a lot easier.

Comment: Side note: if you're interested into code generators, maybe you could have a look at [SpringFuse](http://www.springfuse.com/). It's just for informational purposes, since it's not a Maven plugin as you requested, but it's quite interesting too `;)`

Comment: Well there are a lot of interesting things out there ... think of Spring Roo and others. But I'm more looking for a simple maven tool that I could use wherever I need suff-generation.

Comment: Why do you want specifically a Maven tool? Why not a tool that can be launched from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

There's [minuteproject](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/), which supports a variety of input/output formats. It's not a 100% match to your requirements, but the philosophy is the same: Creating a single generator for all sorts of targets.

I don't think that it has a Maven plugin yet, but the developer is very responsive. I'm sure you could create a feature request for it.

Comment: Well at the moment my own project is allready pretty far. So I'll continue on that path ... but thanks for the info. Perhaps I'll have a look at that and use it as inspiration ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As Lukas mentioned, [Minuteproject](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/) was designed for such things:

1. you can add in various format any text based type (xml, properties, java, html...) file
2. generated file can reference each other
3. the templating language is velocity
4. Templates can be applied on tables/views; column(field); package (groups of tables/views); model; application
5. the code is [updatable](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/Updatable_Generated_Code) (you can add extension; modification area) which means that the code you modified is kept over consecutive generation
6. it is OS and you can modify any template and add yours
7. it bundles tracks such as [JPA2](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/JPA2)
8. It works with convention but you can define your own conventions that apply to your model
9. it is not limited to data structure, it can reverse engineer your statements (SDD - Statement driven development)

But currently it works via command line; a maven plug-in would be a nice improvement

Florian

Answer (score 0):

string-template-maven-plugin maybe the best candidate for "generic" code generator. You can define a string template template group file, and provide a java file to feed data to the template. The plugin will automatically compile and run your java code (controller).

Comment: Actually this doesn't even go near the functioanlity I am looking for. But I have allready started working on a new plugin that I'll use. As soon as that's somewhat finished for a first, I'll opensource it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [write-it-once](https://code.google.com/p/write-it-once/). Template based code generator. You write custom template using [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates), and generate file depending on java reflections. It's the simplest way to generate any file. You can make getters/settest/toString by generating AspectJ or java files, SQL based on JPA annotations, inserts / updates based on enums and so on.